# Flexbox unusual behavior

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

When hovered, the gutter space at the right end of the container div is 0. It should have some space as the justify-content property is set to space-evenly. If the flex-direction property is removed then it acts normal but it gives a jagged animation. What is causing this behavior and is there any other way to achieve this animation. Open to advise and suggestions.

```css
.main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container{
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.circle{
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: pink;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container:hover{
  width: 30rem;
```

```html
<div class="main">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="circle position1"></div>
          <div class="circle position2"></div>
          <div class="circle position3"></div>
          <div class="circle position4"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the jaggedness is because when the direction is set to row, the element adds up to the container div when space available but when it is set to the column it gets hidden because of overflow and the animation is smoother. But when using direction column the problem still persists

Answer (score 1):

It works if you change flex direction from column to row. I'm no expert in animations, but it works having it set to row.

Comment: but the animation is still jagged compared to previous

Comment: the jaggedness is because when the direction is set to row, the element adds up to the container div when space available but when it is set to the column it gets hidden because of overflow and the animation is smoother. But when using direction column the problem still persists.